# jQuery - get id of url and do something (if/else)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to accomplish a 'simple' jQuery effect.
When an user loads their dashboard, and they have a specific `id (#)` in the url, the dashboard should load the content assigned to that specific id.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var pathname = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        if(pathname = loadextra){
            $('.loadextra').addClass('active');
            $('.load-fixed').removeClass('active');
            $('.fixed-ads').hide();
            $('#loader').show().html('<div class="typing_loader_holder"><div class="typing_loader"></div></div>');

            setTimeout(
              function() 
              {
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('.extra-ads').show();
              }, 2000);

        }elseif(pathname = loadfixed){
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.load-extra').removeClass('active');
                $('.extra-ads').hide();
                $('#loader').show().html('<div class="typing_loader_holder"><div class="typing_loader"></div></div>');
                setTimeout(
                  function() 
                  {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $('.fixed-ads').show();
                  }, 2000); 
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
```

So, imagine an user goes to: `http://website.com/user#loadextra` then the code inside `if(pathname = loadextra){}` should be fired off - same goes for `#loadfixed`

Although, as it is now, if you just goes to http://website.com/user, then `if(pathname = loadextra){}` is fired of.

Why doesn't the if/elseif/else statement work in my code?

Comment: `if(pathname = loadextra){` see anything wrong?

Comment: @keune should I use'loadextra' instead? Or maybe double == ?

Comment: you should use double `==`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: I think `elseif` is not correct in JS, try to use `else if` (with a space between else and if).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have make three mistakes:

1) Replace '=' with '==' in if & elseif

2) Replace 'elseif' with 'else if'

3)Replace `$(this).addClass('active');` with `$('.loadfixed').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(pathname == loadextra)
```

Comment: ...Still won't work...